# Copying template from SAN Datastore to local datastore

Tags: vmware-vsphere

I want to copy a template from SAN datastore to local ESXi datastore. How is that possible.
Underlined VMFS for both source and destination datastore is 5.33.

Answer (score 2):

Two ways: Convert template to VM, migrate VM to the local datastore, convert VM to template.  Alternatively you can remove the template from inventory, manually copy the files from one datastore to another, and add the template to inventory again.

See: [Moving or copying virtual disks in a VMware environment (900)](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=900) @vmware.com for the options.

Generally serverfault is for questions that show at least some basic level of research on the part of the person who is asking.  Googling for the answer would have probably put you on the right path immediately.

There's also this: [How should I copy my VM templates between vSphere datacenters?](https://serverfault.com/questions/570833/how-should-i-copy-my-vm-templates-between-vsphere-datacenters) @serverfault.com and while that question is about datacenters it applies to datastores as well.